# My UI is not updating after API call of openweather

Tags: android, json, api, user-interface, android-asynctask

I want to parse JSON from the Openweather API but after many iterations and debugging, my JSON string is not updating, I do not think that there is any problem still the temperatures( minTemperature and maxTemperature) and the name of the place(mPlace) is not set, also I logged the maxtemperature but the console is showing nothing please look into my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText placeText;
private Button enterPlaceButton;
private TextView minTemperature;
private TextView maxTemperature;
private TextView mPlace;
private static final String AppID ="56a5e01eba3af36a7a9b7b210a437d09";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Weather");
    placeText = findViewById(R.id.myPlaceEditText);
    enterPlaceButton = findViewById(R.id.enterPlace);
    minTemperature = findViewById(R.id.minTemperature);
    maxTemperature = findViewById(R.id.maxTemperature);
    mPlace = findViewById(R.id.mPlace);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    final URL[] url = {null};
    enterPlaceButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        url[0] = makeUrl(placeText.getText().toString());
                placeText.setText("");
    });
    if (url[0] != null) {
        MyAsync myAsync = new MyAsync();
        myAsync.execute(url[0]);
    }

    super.onResume();
}

public URL makeUrl(String place) {
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.scheme("http");
    uriBuilder.authority("api.openweathermap.org/");
    uriBuilder.appendPath("data");
    uriBuilder.appendPath("2.5");
    uriBuilder.appendPath("weather");
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("q",place);
    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("appid",AppID);
    try {
        return new URL(uriBuilder.build().toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry could not able to fetch the Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  return null;
}

public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        StringBuilder jsonResponseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    jsonResponseBuilder.append(line);
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry could not able to fetch the Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.d(MyAsync.class.getName(),jsonResponseBuilder.toString());
        return jsonResponseBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        setDataFromJSON(s);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
    public void setDataFromJSON(String s) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject getMainObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
            String maxTemp = getMainObject.getString("temp_max");
            Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), maxTemp);
            maxTemperature.setText(maxTemp);
            String minTemp = getMainObject.getString("temp_min");
            minTemperature.setText(minTemp);
            mPlace.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry could not able to fetch the Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is setDataFromJSON method reached? Also you're making a toast from doInBackground method in case of an exception. It will cause a crash itself, because its an UI operation in the background.

Comment: @Reza I think yes it is accessible as I called setDataFromJSON() method from onPostExecute(String s) which is in the main UI thread.